# How do I hide the rabbits generated by the Youtube Rabbit Hole extension?

Tags: youtube

On the imac, I installed the youtube rabbit hole extension.The video suggestions on the right side are not visible, but an image of a rabbit has appeared.How to delete the image of this rabbit.Thanks.

Comment: I found the answer myself:i highlighted the rabbit image and blocked it with Adblock Plus and the image disappeared

Answer (score 3):

The [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-rabbit-hole/nlddakjbmpidooplakalfoogdincflfh) itself says:

> - *Replace* suggested content with *cute bunnies*!
> - Hide comments (including livestream chats)
> - Disable the trending and subscriptions pages

Which means that the things hidden will be replaced by *cute bunnies*. Since this is a feature of extension itself, it will be there unless the extension is removed (or if it can be - paused). If you wish to remove the image, uninstall the extension and reload the page.

Answer (score 1):

The intention of the Youtube Rabbit Hole extension is to replace the sidebar with rabbit images. If you want to hide the sidebar and also the bunnies, then you can hide specific HTML elements by using dedicated extensions.

In this case, you want to use CSS such as:
`ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer { display: none; }`

https://superuser.com/questions/759745/how-to-block-div-on-website-permanently-using-chrome

Comment: The OP wants to unhide these elements and not hide them.

Comment: But the OP asks "how to delete the image of this rabbit".

Comment: Ah now I thought the OP wanted to get the video suggestions back, but it is also possible that removing the element completely is what hes tryign to to do - sry, your answer makes sense.

Comment: the wording of the question is ambiguous towards whether the OP wants to hide the bunnies, or restore the sidebar. I have edited my answer to make it clear that it only addresses the rabbit images.